# How can I retryWhen function with new params? Angular 9

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

How can I set new param in my request when I got error of authorization

```
myFunc(param): Observable<Visit[]> {
   
    return this.http.get(this.url?session='+param
      ).pipe(map(data => {
            let visitsList = data['visits_grid']
            return visitsList.map(function(visit:any) {
                return {name: visit.client_facility, date: visit.date_start, hash: visit.hash}
        })
    }),
    retryWhen(error => error.pipe(delay(500), take(3))))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having two functions and using a `switchMap`:

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
....
myFunc(param): Observable<Visit[]> {
  return this.makeApiCall().pipe(
    retryWhen(error => error.pipe(
                                   delay(500), 
                                   take(3), 
                                   switchMap(_ => this.makeApiCall({}))), // new param 
  );
}
private makeApiCall(param) {
   return this.http.get(this.url?session='+param
      ).pipe(map(data => {
            let visitsList = data['visits_grid']
            return visitsList.map(function(visit:any) {
                return {name: visit.client_facility, date: visit.date_start, hash: visit.hash}
        })
    }));
}
```